# Последовательное выполнение обработчиков в promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

Есть такого рода код:

```js
'use strict';
console.log('---');

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
};

var promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('загрузился json за секунду'), 1000);
});

function getNewArts(setRandomTime, whatIsThisThen) {
  promise.then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`грузится ${whatIsThisThen}-я пачка артов за ${setRandomTime} мс`);
      },
      setRandomTime);
  });
};

getNewArts(getRandom(1400, 2000), 1); 
getNewArts(getRandom(1400, 2000), 2);
getNewArts(getRandom(1400, 2000), 3);
```

Этот код призван эмулировать загрузку json с сервера, а затем добавление в ДОМ картинок.
Для объяснения разберу код по порядку.
Строки `'use strict'`, `'console,log('---');` и функция `getRandom()`, надеюсь, не нуждаются в пояснениях.
Далее я создаю новый `promise`, который эмулирует здесь загрузку json с сервера. Для эмуляции асинхронности в примере я использую **таймеры**.
Далее идет функция `getNewArts()`, которая добавляет в ДОМ картинки (добавлять их нужно после того, как будет загружен json (в нем url к ним), поэтому использую `promise` (обещания так называемые).
Добавлять же картинки в ДОМ нужно только после того, как вся новая пачка загрузилась. Для эмуляции загрузки новой пачки картинок используется таймер, время загрузки генерируется функцией случайных чисел.
Дальше идет, собственно, вызов функции `getNewArts()`, которая загружает новую пачку.
И вот тут у меня вопрос: ведь понятно, что время загрузки картинок может быть разным, а нужно, чтобы пачки картинок были добавлены в соответствии с их готовой загрузкой в кеше, тогда как выполнять каждый обработчик `.then` последовательно, после выполнения установленного перед этим?
В консоли выводится текст с временем от самого минимального до максимального, это означает, что все обработчики начинают выполняются сразу же.
Как исправить код, чтобы было последовательное выполнение?

Вывод консоли сами можете запустить в сниппете. Может быть так, что с первой попытки выведет правильную последовательность загрузки (1, 2, 3), но не верьте этому, запустите тест повторно. 
А вот, как хотелось бы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Обращаю внимание на время эмулируемой загрузки картинок, а также на последовательность выполнения обработчиков `.then` - они идут по порядку, ведь картинки могут грузится разное время, а выводить их нужно последовательно.

Comment: вот вроде написал много, а чего хочешь получить так и непонятно

Comment: @Grundy, чтоб обработчики `.then`, которые я навесил через вызов функции `getNewArts()`, выполнялись последовательно, а не все одновременно и сразу.

Comment: Добавь какой-нибудь пример вывода в сниппет, чтобы было видно сейчас вот так, а нужно вот так

Comment: @Grundy, расписал всё подробнее как мог. Подробнее уже некуда, мне кажется...

Comment: примера текущего вывода и примера ожидаемого вывода в вопросе нет. поэтому неизвестно что же именно ты хочешь получить на выходе

Comment: @Grundy, добавил-добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сделать очередь (как выяснилось, именно это надо сделать), можно сделать так (рекурсия):

```js
'use strict';
console.log('---');

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
};

var promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('загрузился json за секунду'), 1000);
});

function getNewArts(setRandomTime, whatIsThisThen) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        res(`грузится ${whatIsThisThen}-я пачка артов за ${setRandomTime} мс`);
      },
      setRandomTime);
  });
};


class Queue{
  constructor(data = []){
    if(!Array.isArray(data))
      data = [];
      
    this.data = data;
    this._processing = false;
    
    if(data.length)
      this.handle();
  }
  
  handle(){
    // Выходим, если больше нет элементов
    if(this.data.length){
      this._processing = true;
    
      // Spread'им элементы очередного вызова
      getNewArts(...this.data.shift())
        .then(result => {
          // Обрабатываем результат
          console.info(result);

          // Если данные остались после извлечения, запускаем ещё раз обработку
          if(this.data.length)
            this.handle();
          else
            this._processing = false;
        });
     }
  }
  
  add(...data){
    this.data.push(data);
    
    if(!this._processing)
      this.handle();
  }
}

let queue = new Queue();

queue.add(getRandom(1400, 2000), 1);
queue.add(getRandom(1400, 2000), 2);
queue.add(getRandom(1400, 2000), 3);
```

Comment: Ага, правильно понял.  Я и сам уже нашел про `.all`, но написать ответ  завтра утром планировал, опередил) Спасибо.

Comment: Единственное для полноты не хватает преждней логики: "загрузка" картинок должна выполняться после "загрузки" json. А у тебя получается, что он вообще не участвует тут. Правда это легко поправляется да и вопрос не в этом-то.

Comment: @VostokSisters, деталей я не расписывал, ибо не был особо уверен что правильно понял. Но суть, надеюсь, донёс. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Хотя не, знаешь, это не совсем ответ на вопрос. `.all` выполняет промис, когда уже все промисы завершились. Конкретно по вопросу: это не последовательное выполнение инструкций `.then`, которые я описывал. А по логике моего вопроса скажу, что это ведь нелогично, что мы грузим 3 пачки картинок и выводим все 3 только после того, когда они будут загружены. То есть если 1-я пачка загрузилась быстрее, то её надо бы вывести, но не выводить остальные, если они не готовы. А если 2-я загрузилась быстрее, то не выводить её, пока первая не будет готова.

Comment: @VostokSisters, так бы и написал. Тогда очевидно: разрешился промис 1 - обрабатываем вывод и вызываем промис 2 и т. д.

Comment: Так что я всё-таки сниму галку, это не последовательное выполнение обещаний, а выполнение своего обещания после возврата `resolve()` всеми остальными. Они не последовательно исполняются.

Comment: @VostokSisters, снимать или одевать - Ваше право. сейчас перепишу на Ваше требование.

Comment: Так сказать: поставить в очередь на выполнение. Так корректнее было бы.

Comment: @VostokSisters, так?

Comment: Да, большое спасибо. Технически всё корректно и по вопросу. Черт, но честно говоря мне нужно в разных частях кода вызывать метод `getNewArts()` (посмотри как в конце кода в вопросе он вызывается 3 раза), а не всё одной очередью. Не мог бы ты подправить так, чтобы можно было одним методом вызывать подгрузку одной новой пачки, ставить её на очередь?

Comment: @VostokSisters, так?

Comment: Да, спасибо, всё так теперь, работает как надо) Единственное что - код какой-то сложный для меня пока что :D Впервые увидел, что в js есть классы. Но с этим я как-нибудь разберусь.

Comment: @VostokSisters, капля упорности и будет понятно :) Удачи.

Comment: Слушай, я обыскался уже, что это за `...data` в методе `add` в конструкторе `Queue`?  Что за точки и что они делают? И как гуглить, чтобы поискать об этом побольше?

Comment: @VostokSisters, это `Spread/rest` оператор. Ознакомится можно [тут](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-spread-rest).